# Audio Streaming: Prevent "Application Terminated" While on Background

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I'm working on an audio streaming app but application is terminated after 30 seconds on a few devices. Users can stream the audio on background, but sometimes it just stops and the app is terminated.

This is very annoying and hard to track down as it only affects a few devices and not all the time. This is what the log shows:

```
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: release
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: setListener
     disconnected
V/MediaPlayer-JNI: destructor
     disconnected
W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
D/ContentValues: onDestroy
Application terminated.
```

Looks like the app is simple killed by the OS.

"mediaplayer went away with unhandled events" is a common issue when the audio file was not properly started, but on this case the error occurs on streaming after 30 seconds.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class SoundService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

public void onCreate() {

    Log.i("Script", "onCreate");

    if(player == null){
        try {
            Log.i("Script", "onCreate: Try");
            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource("enter url");
            player.prepareAsync();

            player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            player.setOnErrorListener(this);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);

        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (SecurityException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }
    else{
        Log.i("Script", "onCreate: start");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

Here are the listeners:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i("Script", "onPrepared()");
    player.start();

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Script", "onStartCommand");
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try to make the service as foreground to see if its an issue with the new services api

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are starting the media player in a Service with a notification with startForeground. This should hold on to the Service without letting the OS kill it.